# Different result between Serial.print and Serial.printf in ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32

I want to print my string variable using printf method:

id = 6415F1BF713C

```
  Serial.printf("id: %s\n\n", id);
  Serial.print(id);
```

The result that I got was:

```
id: ⸮⸮⸮?
6415F1BF713C
```

is there any thing that's wrong?

Thanks.

Update :

```
//get device id
String getDeviceID() {
  uint64_t chipid = ESP.getEfuseMac(); // The chip ID is essentially its MAC address(length: 6 bytes).
  uint16_t chip = (uint16_t)(chipid >> 32);

  char devID[40];
  snprintf(devID, 40, "%04X%08X", chip, (uint32_t)chipid);

  return devID;
}
String id = getDeviceID();

Serial.printf("id: %s\n\n", id);
Serial.print(id);
```

Comment: what data type has the variable `id`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't offer enough code to properly debug this, but I'm guessing what you mean is

```
String id = "6415F1BF713C";

Serial.printf("id: %s\n\n", id);
Serial.print(id);
```

The `%s` format in the `printf()` method expects to take a C/C++ `char *`, not a `String`. When you passed it a `String`, it printed the memory address of the `String` object - four characters which would appear as garbage, as you saw.

C and C++ use `char *` (pointers to characters) and `char []` (arrays of characters) to represent strings. These are different from the Arduino `String` class, and people often confuse them.

To use the `printf()` method with a `String` you need to get its C string pointer, like this:

```
Serial.printf("id: %s\n\n", id.c_str());
```

The reason that this:

```
Serial.print(id);
```

works is that the `print()` method has a form that specifically expects to take a `String` object as an argument.

Comment: Hi romkey, I have update the code. thanks for your reply.

Comment: If that solved your problem please accept the answer so that other people will know it's a solution.